# Sum of two orthogonal projections - equivalent properties

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, orthogonality

I am trying to prove the following equivalences.

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the orthogonal projections on the closed subspaces $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively. The following are equivalent:

(i) $P_1+P_2$ is an orthogonal projection
(ii) $P_1P_2 = 0$
(iii) $M_1\perp M_2$

I have proved $(ii) \to (iii)$, any hint on the other implications would be precious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me prove (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii), while giving you some more time to think about (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i), which is
not so hard.

By hypothesis  $$
  P_1+P_2=
(P_1+P_2)^2 =
  P_1^2+P_1P_2+P_2P_1+P_2^2 =
  P_1+P_1P_2+P_2P_1+P_2.
  $$
so $P_2P_1=-P_1P_2$.  Left multiplying the above by  $P_2$ we get
$$
  P_2P_1=-P_2P_1P_2.
  $$
Since $P_2P_1P_2$ is self-adjoint, then so is $P_2P_1$.  But then
$$
  P_1P_2=  P_1^*P_2^*= (P_2P_1)^* = P_2P_1 = -P_1P_2,
  $$
whence $P_1P_2=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I proved (3) implies (2), but I am stuck in proving (2) implies (1). I don't know how to prove that $(P_1+P_2)^2=P_1+P_2$, do you have a hint? Thanks again

Comment: Hypothesis (i) says that   $P_1+P_2$ is a projection, and all projections $P$ are idempotent:  given any $x$, one has that
$P(x)$ is in the range of $P$, and $P$ is the identity there.  Thus $P$ sends $P(x)$ to itself, hence $P^2=P$.

Comment: When I said "...time to think about (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" I actually meant "(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)", as I have now
corrected in the last edit.  This should not be too hard.